# How to search a multi-dimensional array by multiple values at once in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter

Given the following 2D array:

```
$data_info_array = array( 
array( 
    'score'   => '100', 
    'name'    => 'Alice', 
    'subject' => 'Data Structures'
), 
array( 
    'score'   => '50', 
    'name'    => 'Bob', 
    'subject' => 'Advanced Algorithms'
), 
array( 
    'score'   => '75', 
    'name'    => 'Charlie', 
    'subject' => 'Distributed Computing'
) 
); 

// this gets the key when I search for the score of 50 from one column
$index = array_search('50', array_column($data_info_array, 'score')); 
echo $index;
```

If I want to search by two values I can only think of something like:

```
 $index1 = array_search('50', array_column($data_info_array, 'score')); 
 $index2 = array_search('Bob', array_column($data_info_array, 'name')); 
 $real_index = ( $index1 === $index2 ) ? $index1 : null;
```

Is there a way I can search for score of '50' and name of 'Bob' together and get the index to that only if that combo exists? Is there a better way do do than what I've come up with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build your search query as an array and compare the intersection of each item with it.

```
$search = ['score' => '50', 'name' => 'Bob'];

foreach($data_info_array as $k => $v) {
    if ( $search === array_intersect($v, $search) ) {
        echo $k;
        break;
    }
}
```

@mickmackusa noticed it is safer to use `array_intersect_assoc()` here. He's right because when the multi-dimensional array items are unpredictable, nothing forbids to have items like that:

```
['miaou' => '50', 'graou' => 'Bob', 'score' => '50', 'name' => 'Bob']
```

where the searched values are also present but for other keys. In this case `array_intersect()` returns *all* correct values (with their corresponding keys of course) regardless the keys in `$search`, and the comparison with the search array will return `false`.

But using `array_intersect_assoc()`, you ensure that only values for keys in `$search` are taken in account.

Conclusion: If you let yourself be lulled into sleep by the seeming monotony of multidimensional array items, you won't be immune to [surprise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkC-EYg7Gno) when unexpected variations arise.

Comment: Safer to use `array_intersect_assoc($search, $v)`, right @Cas?

Comment: @mickmackusa: You can also use `array_intersect_assoc()` but not sure you obtain something more performant or safer, because *in fine*, the comparison decides if the item is present or not, and without the correct keys, the comparison returns `false` whatever the values in the intersection.

Comment: @mickmackusa: But I see what you mean, an alien item like that: `array_intersect(['50', 'Bob', 'score'=>'50', 'name'=>'Bob'],['score' => '50', 'name' => 'Bob'])`.

Comment: Removing 'break;' will allow for all matches to be returned (if for example, there was a case where more than one item had a score of 50).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `array_filter()`, which allows you to do as many checks on the contents as you need at the same time...

```
$output = array_filter($data_info_array, function ($data) {
    return $data['score'] == 50 && $data['name'] == 'Bob';
});
```

This will give you a list of the matches, so you may need to do `[0]` (and check if only 1 is returned) if you need a single match.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice one-liner, utilizing PHP arrow functions

```
$name = "Alice";
$score = "100";

$result = array_filter($data_info_array, fn($data) => $data['name'] == $name && $data['score'] == $score );

print_r($result);
```