# Search for unique row in a multidimensional array using an associative array containing two elements

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array, filtering

I'm trying to get the values from the second array which match the associative elements from the first array.

`$array1` can only possibly match one row (at most) with the qualifying `sr_no` and `batch_id` values because the combination of these two columns will always provide uniqueness. **In other words**, when a match is found, there will be no chance of making another match in the remaining data.

```
$array1 = ['sr_no' => 72, 'batch_id' => 1];

$array2 = [ 
    ['quantity' => 22, 'sr_no' => 71, 'batch_id' => 2, 'inq_id' => 91],
    ['quantity' => 35, 'sr_no' => 72, 'batch_id' => 1, 'inq_id' => 92],
    ['quantity' => 20, 'sr_no' => 69, 'batch_id' => 3, 'inq_id' => 90],  
];
```

Expected Output:

```
['quantity' => 35, 'sr_no' => 72, 'batch_id' => 1, 'inq_id' => 92]
```

I tried with `$result = array_diff_assoc($array2, $array1);`, but it's printing the entire `$array2` array values.

Comment: @mickmackusa Only one match will be there in the $array2 with the sr_no and batch_id combination

Comment: Mostly a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/60550780/2943403

Comment: Also near dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/40422038/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stop iterating as soon as a match is found.

If your `$array1` is designed to be flexible, use `array_intersect_assoc()` to return the matching elements, then check that all required matches are found.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Gsigg))

```
$array1 = ['sr_no' => 72, 'batch_id' => 1];

$array2 =
[ 
    ['quantity' => 22, 'sr_no' => 71, 'batch_id' => 2, 'inq_id' => 91],
    ['quantity' => 35, 'sr_no' => 72, 'batch_id' => 1, 'inq_id' => 92],
    ['quantity' => 20, 'sr_no' => 69, 'batch_id' => 3, 'inq_id' => 90],  
];

$result = null;
foreach ($array2 as $row) {
    if (array_intersect_assoc($array1, $row) === $array1) {
        $result = $row;
        break;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'quantity' => 35,
  'sr_no' => 72,
  'batch_id' => 1,
  'inq_id' => 92,
)
```